# Global statements used within a local function scope

Tags: python, function, namespaces

I though I was fully aware of how LEGB rule worked until I came across this. Essentially I am to access the "total" variable within my function local namespace. I know the "total variable is a local namespace but for whatever reason when I try to run this function I get the following error:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'total' referenced before assignment

Example:

```
total = 0

def two_digit_sum(n):
    for i in str(n):
        total += int(i)
    return total


number = 111
print(two_digit_sum(number))
```

**However** when I utilize the following function , I do not come across the error
Example:

```
def spam():
    print(eggs)


eggs = 42
spam()
```

^^^
As you can see the eggs variable is also a global function.

Comment: You can read (and even mutate) variables from outer scopes without having to do anything special, but you can't reassign an outer scope's name.  Your first function reassigns `total`, your second function doesn't reassign `eggs`.

Comment: 'I know the "total variable is a local namespace"' then I don't think I understand why you are confused. If you remove the line `total = 0`, do you then expect the code to work? What if you had written `total += 0` rather than `total = 0` in the first place? Would you expect that to work if `total` hadn't separately been defined yet?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, that was a complete typo. I meant to say that I know "total" variable is a global name space

Comment: Ah, okay. The linked duplicate should answer your question, then.

Comment: @Samwise careful with the word "mutate" in this context. You *can't* mutate *variables* from outer scopes - mutating a variable is generally synonymous with *assigning/re-assigning it*. You can, of course, mutate *objects* that the variable refers to.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you have done is you have given  value for `total` inside the function  so you have to make it a `global variable`.

But in eggs you have done no new value and just printed it.

This code is the solution to you problem.

```
total = 0

def two_digit_sum(n):
    global total

    for i in str(n):
        total += int(i)
    return total


number = 111
print(two_digit_sum(number))
```

But if you have given  a value of `eggs` inside the function `spam` you will get the error.

```
def spam():
    eggs += 1 
    print(eggs)
    
eggs = 42
spam()
```

here where you have made a value to it.